# Using page break on a hidden div

Tags: css, image, html, page-break

How can I get `page-break-after` to work on a div that I am showing as `display:none` with `@media screen`?

I want the image to only show when I print but also page break after it so the rest of the divs print onto the second page.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2SjvD/1/)

this is the result I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current CSS you have:

```
@media screen { .image { display:none; } }

@media print { .image { break-after:always;} }

.one { width:200px; height:100px; background-color:#339999;}
```

Where you have:

```
     @media print { .image { break-after:always;} }
```

Try changing this to:

```
     @media print { .image { page-break-after:always;} }
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've already tried `page-break-after` previously but it also doesn't work

Comment: And it all has been printed on the same page?

Comment: Yes, if you see my example image, that's how it prints

Comment: What browser are you using? Works for me

Comment: Download it and try that 1 in chrome, i just created it. works for me in Chrome. if doesnt work, try updating it

Comment: @SturnsEye let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51580/discussion-between-nick-prozee-and-saturnseye)

Comment: Ah, it's working now! it was because I never added a `display` after page break

Answer (score 1):

This is for other people watching this review.
The new css file, I deleted my download link so here it is:

```
.image { display:none;}

@media print 
{ 
.image { page-break-after:always; display:table;} 
.one {display:table;}
}

.one { width:200px; height:100px; background-color:#339999;}
```